# Google Maps Javascript API V3 - Geocode adress

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I want to use the Google Maps Javascript API V3 in order to geocode user's input address on the client-side. 
My question is about the usage limit where google states:

> The Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.

[The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en#Limits)

But I'm not really sure what google means by that. Can I use the geocode service in order to geocode address and not show it on a google maps (if I don't need to). Can I just store it directly store it in the database on a server? This geocode will be used later through a mobile app and the geocoded data will be displayed on google maps in the actual Android application.

Does this seem legal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of service (legal issues) not coding.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but since it's good that you want to be in compliance, and even though we can't answer for Google, here's what their terms say in direct answer to your questions...

**Your question:**

> Can I use the geocode service in order to geocode address and not show it on a google maps (if I don't need to).

**The answer:**

> The Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.

**Next question:**

> Can I just store it directly store it in the database on a server? This geocode will be used later through a mobile app and the geocoded data will be displayed on google maps in the actual Android application.

**The answer:** (see the [Google Maps TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms), section 10)

> (b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily (and in no event for more than 30 calendar days), securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.
>
> (c) No Mass Downloads or Bulk Feeds of Content. You must not use the Service in a manner that gives you or any other person access to mass downloads or bulk feeds of any Content, including but not limited to numerical latitude or longitude coordinates, imagery, visible map data, or places data (including business listings). For example, you are not permitted to offer a batch geocoding service that uses Content contained in the Maps API(s).